# How to Change Sandbox Tester Auto-renewable Subscription Rate in App Store Connect?

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, ios-simulator, revenuecat

This is my first time implementing am autorenewable subscription service for my app. I use RevenueCat and everything works on their end. The subscription part of my app charges users per week and the initial purchase gives users a 2 week trial period, which means they have 2 weeks before the initial subscription expires.

I submitted my app for review and I got a rejection

> Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> We are not able to continue our review because we need access to a
> demo account with an expired subscription to review the entire
> purchase flow.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, provide a user name and password for a demo
> account with expired subscriptions in the App Review Information
> section of App Store Connect.

The issue is when I make a sandbox test purchase, the expiration date is 2 weeks from now. **How can I force a faster expiration date/change the auto-renewable rate?** If I can’t, then I have to wait 2 weeks until I can give this to the reviewer.

Here are the purchase printouts from RevenueCat

```
latestPurchaseDate= 2023-11-05 22:14:03 +0000
originalPurchaseDate= 2023-11-05 22:14:03 +0000
expirationDate= 2023-11-19 22:14:03 +0000
```

I went to App Store Connect > Users and Access > Sandbox Testers and when I clicked the sandbox test email I'm using it says

```
Subscription Renewal Rate?
 Monthly renewal every 5 minutes.
```

I don't see anything for weekly, daily, etc ...

[image]

[image]

Not sure if this matters but I'm using a simulator and I'm logged in with the sandbox email on the simulator and in its iCloud. I also used the same sandbox email/pw before I made the initial purchase when the Apple alert appears and asks for those credentials before you can make a purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730115) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704214?answerId=710545022#710545022). In short if you have weekly subscriptions like me pick `Monthly Renewal Every 30 Seconds` as explained below. This will expedite your test renewal transactions.

To test your purchase on a Simulator in Xcode and to adjust the renewal rate (**it doesn't matter what the App Store Connect Sandbox tester renewal rate is**).

Xcode Steps:

1- Select whatever you named your [StoreKit Configuration File](https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/apple-app-store#ios-14-only-testing-on-the-simulator).

2- Select `Editor` from top menu.

3- Select `Subscription Renewal Rate`.

4- Choose a renewal rate of `Monthly Renewal Every 30 Seconds`.

[image]

App Store Connect and Xcode no longer have weekly Subscription Renewal Rates, they only offer monthly as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704214?answerId=710545022#710545022)

> Although the subscription renewal rates in Xcode 13.2 and later are in
> terms of a monthly renewal, you can still use these rates to modify
> the rate subscriptions of durations other than monthly renew at. The
> rates will extrapolate to be roughly proportional to how the monthly
> renewal changes. These rates are identical to the rates in the sandbox
> environment, so you can use the table on the Test in app purchases
> document as a reference.
>
> There are time rate options unique to StoreKit Testing in Xcode: Real
> Time, and Monthly Renewal Every 30 Seconds. Here is how the latter
> effects durations:
>
> • 1 week: 10 seconds • 1 month: 30 seconds • 2 months: 1 minute • 3
> months: 90 seconds • 6 months: 3 minutes • 1 year: 6 minutes